# Extract sample and set column name

Tags: r, dplyr

My `y` datframe as a single column: `CustomerKey`.

I'm extracting a sample of 1.000 observations from that column and assigning it to `temp` datafame.

```
temp <- sample_n(as.data.frame(y[,1]), 1000)
```

This is returing a dataframe with the column name `y[,1]`

How do I set the column name to `CustomerKey` in  the same operation, preferably using `dplyr` pipes?

Comment: Because you used `as.data.frame(y[,1])`  instead it can be `data.frame(CustomerKey = y[,1])`

Comment: @thanks, without it, I get the error: Error: `tbl` must be a data frame, not an integer vector

Comment: Base R solution: `temp  = y[sample(nrow(y), 1000), , drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to use `tidyverse`

```
colNm <- "CustomerKey"
tibble(!! colNm := y[,1]) %>% 
            sample_n(1000)
```